# How to send the email verification email from Laravel 5.7 from custom route

Tags: php, laravel

I need to Send Active Link From My Route

```
 Route::get('user/{user}/settings', 'UserController@settings');
```

I tried this but it goes to main page

```
     <a href="{{ route('verification.resend') }}">{{ __('click here to request another') }}</a>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate little more about what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel includes the `Auth\VerificationController` class that contains the necessary logic to send verification links and verify emails. To register the necessary routes for this controller, pass the verify option to the `Auth::routes` method:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

(From https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification)